# Elasticsearch: Filtering by date and time as different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a filter for my query using a date range and a time range. In my case, date and time are different fields. So I want to run queries like: Show me all the events happening this month (15-10-01/15-10-30) between 10:00:00 am and 12:00:00

This is my query, but it is not working. Note: If I only use the "date part" it works, but with the combination of the time field, the results are wrong.

Any suggestion?

```
{"query": {
    "filtered": {
         "query": {
             "match": { "message" : "error" }
         },
         "filter": {
             "bool" : {
                 "must" : {
                     "range": {
                         "date": {
                             "gte": "15-11-01",
                             "lte": "15-11-30"
                         }
                     }
                 },
                 "must" : {
                     "range": {
                         "time": {
                             "gte": "10:00:00",
                             "lte": "12:00:00"
                         }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
  }
}
}
```

**Update:** Running the command:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping
```

As some of you suggested, I could discover that ES is defining the "time" field type as string and not as (date) time.
Additionally, as it was pointed in the first answer, my query syntax was wrong.

Comment: Does elasticsearch support the time format, i.e. does it know how to apply lte and gte to times of day?

Comment: What mapping do you have for `time`?

Comment: In the logstash config file, those fields are mapped in this way: %{DATE:date} %{TIME:time}

Comment: What @AndreiStefan referred to was the mapping you have in your Elasticsearch server, i.e. what you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is not correct is that you have two `must` clause inside your `bool` filter. That is not valid JSON and so that might be the reason why your query doesn't work, try the following query instead which has the two `range` filters inside the `bool/must` filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "message": "error"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "15-11-01",
                  "lte": "15-11-30"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "time": {
                  "gte": "10:00:00",
                  "lte": "12:00:00"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```