# ElasticSearch: How to query a date field using an hours-range filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, I already know how to filter a days range from a (timestamp) date field. That's an easy one:

```
"range": {
    "date": {
        "gte": "2015-11-01",
        "lte": "2015-11-30"
    }
}
```

But how to filter dates when you are interested in ranges based on hours like gte:"8:00:00" and lte:"10:00:00"? Is this possible?

My requirement in other words:
How to get all the events happening this month (15-11-01/15-11-30) but only between 8:00:00 am and 10:00:00?

Comment: Between those hours, for any day?

Comment: Let's say I want to get all the records between 2015-10-01 and 2015-12-31, but only those that happened between this hour range: "8:00:00" and "10:00:00"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch: Filtering by date and time as different fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508044/elasticsearch-filtering-by-date-and-time-as-different-fields)

Comment: Similar question, but not the same. In the other one, I assume that there is another field called "time", that changes the problem.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it with your `range` filter to filter the correct days and then with a `script` filter to filter the desired hours, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "2015-11-01",
                  "lte": "2015-11-30"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() >= params.min && doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() <= params.max",
                  "params": {
                    "min": 8,
                    "max": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this query to work.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. By the way, I tried to add another script to filter minutes using the method "getMinuteOfHour" but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Val could you please tell me from where `getHourOfDay()` method comes? does groovy script engine uses `joda` for datetime manipulation? I could not find any documentation

Comment: @ChintanShah25 yep, `doc['field'].date` returns a Joda [`MutableDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html) object for all fields of type `date` or `long`. Agreed, it's not explicitly mentioned in the official docs, but you can find that info the [original ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/220) from 2010.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly then I think you have to add new field which indexes only time like

```
PUT your_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "time": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2015-11-01",
              "lte": "2015-11-30"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "08:00:00",
              "lte": "10:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Right now, my field "date" has this type: {"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}, it supports records like this 2015-11-04T22:10:02 and unfortunately I can't modify my indexes

Comment: even in my application, I have the same format but thing is you can only search like `"gte" : "2015-10-02T13:34:09", "lte" : "2015-10-05T12:00:00"` which will give you results between that range and not what you want which is specific time range on specific days

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I once used to only get results from start of current day to 6pm:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(log_message:\"My Search String\")"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "CET",
              "gt": "now-24h/d",
              "lte": "now-24h/d+18h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the important part is "now-24h/d" which will round to midnight / begin of current day, although it is a bit tricky as it depends on whether you use gt/lt(e), see [reference doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_math_and_rounding) for details.

Comment: Can you tell me whether my syntax is correct for my scenario . Want to fetch the date from Previous Day 7pm to today 7pm   range.setGte("now-1d/d+19h");
        range.setLte("now-24h/d+19h")

Comment: I think it should be `range.setGte("now-2d/d+19h");` for 7pm previous Day..? But can't check.