# Elasticsearch Query: How to get all the events happening in a period of days, but only between 8:00:00 am and 10:00:00am?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a query to get all events for specific days and hours.

Ex.
    for the period 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-15, but only events happens between 08:00am - 10:00am

The following query is getting alerts for the specific period of days, how to add to this script the section to filter for specific hours?

```
    {
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2016-01-01",
                            "lte": "2016-01-15"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

regards!

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535092/elasticsearch-how-to-query-a-date-field-using-an-hours-range-filter/33537029#33537029

Comment: thanks for your reply @Val I'm trying using script execution, however I'm getting an error during the execution:

Comment: "index": "xt-history-2015.11.26",
            "shard": 0,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "QueryPhaseExecutionException[[xt-history-2015.11.26][0]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(alert.dateModified:[1446336000000 TO 1480550399999]) +ScriptFilter(doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() <= max)))],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for [date] in mapping with types []]]; "

Comment: How is your date field called? dateModified? if yes, then your script needs to be `doc.dateModified.date.getHourOfDay()`

Comment: @Val    Greate, this is working...   thanks a lot for your quick support.