# Elasticsearch -- determine if a given time is within a TIME range

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: v7.2 
Application: Laravel v5.7

I am trying to query to whether my document belongs to a certain time range

Here's my Index's `mav_time_aired` field mapping:

[image]

Now I want to filter or fetch documents that are within a certain time range (I want to retrieve documents with `mav_time_aired` value within `06:00:00` to `09:00:00` **OR** `18:00:00` to `22:00:00`, so I have this kind of query:

```
$temp =
[
    "bool" => [
        "should" => [
            [
                "range" => [
                    "mav_time_aired" => [
                        "gte" => "06:00:00",
                        "lte" => "09:00:00",
                        'format' => "HH:mm:ss",
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "range" => [
                    "mav_time_aired" => [
                        "gte" => "18:00:00",
                        "lte" => "22:00:00",
                        'format' => "HH:mm:ss",
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ]
    ]
];
```

With the use of `format` property, according to the documentation, I must be able to literally format the data of the document into my desired format.

Now with the given query, I am expecting that I should be able to fetch my desired output, but unfortunately, the query results to:

`No result found` or `Empty`

But looking into my documents, I have these documents:

[image]

[image]

(These are just 2 from the documents I have determined that are supposed to be retrieved)

Did I miss something from my Elasticsearch query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535092/elasticsearch-how-to-query-a-date-field-using-an-hours-range-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this isn't escalated yet, I resorted somewhat doing the hardcoded `script` elasticsearch provides for its users

I made a code something like this:

```
$temp =
[
    "bool" => [
        "must" => [
            "script" => [
                "script" => [
                    "source" => "(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 6 && !(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 9 && doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getMinute() >= 0)) || (doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 18 && !(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 22 && doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getMinute() >= 0))",
                    "lang" => "painless"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

and for the else I simply added the `must_not` boolean query of Elasticsearch:

```
$temp =
[
    "bool" => [
        "must_not" => [
            "script" => [
                "script" => [
                    "source" => "(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 6 && !(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 9 && doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getMinute() >= 0)) || (doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 18 && !(doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getHour() >= 22 && doc['mav_time_aired'].value.getMinute() >= 0))",
                    "lang" => "painless"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Then I was able to fetch my desired documents