# specific hour range query in elasticsearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanna get an idea of query in elasticsearch 7.x.

can i convert my query to specific hour range of a week ?

=> e.g) 8a.m ~ 3p.m every single day in 7 days

now my query (just 7days) :

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "statusAt": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2019-11-04T02:54:28.625Z",
              "lte": "2019-11-11T02:54:28.625Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33537029/4604579

Comment: @Val I already saw it. but i cant use it like that. error message is `"[script] query does not support [params]"`

Comment: That was for older version of ES. I modified my answer to make it work with latest versions, please try again

Comment: @Val I changed it as your answer. but error message is `"Variable [min] is not defined."`

Comment: Well, missing params, try again.

Comment: @Val thanks for your answer. but your answer cant solve my case.

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: @Val I found how to solve it. it is little different with your last answer. i will make answer myself in this case. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve it.

It is different with little in each version.

my case is elasticsearch 7.x version. and I found solution in public documentation in elastic.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "statusAt": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "2019-11-04T02:54:28.625Z",
              "lte": "2019-11-11T02:54:28.625Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['date'].value.getHour() >= params.min && doc['date'].value.getHour() <= params.max",
              "params": {
              "min": 9,
              "max": 15
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

> Refer to :
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33537029/4604579
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-expression.html