# elasticsearch find doc by time with datetime field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to retrieve all documents that have a date between 2 dates and a time between 2 hours.

I can't get the query to work.

Is it possible ? If yes, how.

```
[
    {
        "_index": "a1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "50c09e31-1fad-4d25-ab9d-35154a1b765b",
        "_score": 5.0,
        "_source":
        {
            "start_at": "2022-06-23 14:00",
            "end_at": "2022-06-23 14:15",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "a1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "d96ba291-63de-422a-9123-3d1a1d573861",
        "_score": 5.0,
        "_source":
        {
            "start_at": "2022-06-24 16:30",
            "end_at": "2022-06-24 17:00",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

> GET /a1/_search?pretty
> {
> "query": {
> "bool": {
> "must": [
> {
> "range": {
> "start_at": {
> "gte": "2022-06-20",
> "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "range": {
> "start_at": {
> "lt": "2022-06-27",
> "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "range": {
> "start_at": {
> "gte": "14:00",
> "format": "HH:mm"
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "range": {
> "start_at": {
> "lt": "18:00",
> "format": "HH:mm"
> }
> }
> },
> ]
> }
> },
> "size": 10
> }

Thanks.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535092/elasticsearch-how-to-query-a-date-field-using-an-hours-range-filter/33537029#33537029

Comment: Thank you.
Doesn't works for me "Illegal list shortcut value [date]" or "dynamic method [org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Dates, getHourOfDay/0] not found"

Comment: Have you tried`doc['start_at'].date.getHourOfDay()` ?

Comment: yes :) "Illegal list shortcut value [date]."

Comment: Replace `date` with `value`, i.e. `doc['start_at'].value.getHourOfDay()` since that has changed in the more recent versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate solution would be to use a query similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535092/elasticsearch-how-to-query-a-date-field-using-an-hours-range-filter/33537029#33537029) but change the script part to:

```
doc['start_at'].value.getHourOfDay() ...
```

Since scripting can be bad for performance, a better solution would be to index the hours into a dedicated field and then perform a `range` query on it.

Comment: thank you.
I have no choice, I have to create new fields because I can't filter correction on hours and minutes at the same time. :(